# Image matrix style transforms for CSS content?

Tags: css, webgl, css-transforms

So I'm looking at a specific application for a web browser which requires me to express color as a straight alpha channel with a black and white alpha channel as a separate element. (an [example of both types](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/aftereffects/cs/using/WS3878526689cb91655866c1103906c6dea-7f7ea.html)

I know many moons ago, IE supported some perverse filter options, but since I'm doing css3 transforms, I need this to work in a modern browser, preferably Chrome.

Basically what I'd like to do is have an element with CSS transforms applied, specifically rotation most likely, then I'd like to take that and copy it to another equivalently sized element which has the black / white transformation applied. An additional bonus would be setting the original element to use straight alpha, but I can live without that for now.

I haven't been able to find any routes with which to start investigating. If you have one, I'd be super grateful. My last resort is to start doing things in WebGL or Canvas and modifying the output there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually figured out the answer... it's CSS Shaders.

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/custom/index.html

Not yet available, but soon.

The reason not to use Canvas is for simplicity in authoring. (Long story.)

Answer (score 0):

Two or three different elements stacked on top of each other using absolute positioning and z-index? This would require you to save two different images which I'm guessing you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do CSS 3D transforms. Browser support is basically there in newer IE, Chrome, Firefox, iOS and Android.

- [where can you use them](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d)
- [how to use them](http://www.eleqtriq.com/2010/05/understanding-css-3d-transforms/)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms)